# How to use SolrNet index byte array data to field?

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

This is my object

```
    public virtual string id { get; set; }
    public virtual string title { get; set; }
    public virtual string links { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] binary { get; set; }
```

Comment: So what do you want to do with the binary data? What kind of data is it? What have you tried? Which problems did you encounter?

Comment: I need to index the document files, but some file it has including attachment so if i just use solrnet to parse content it will does not index attachment, so i thing if i just index the binary data, maybe it will work.

Comment: But what do you want to achieve by attaching the binary data? "Indexing binary data" doesn't mean anything by itself. Do you want to be able to search inside it? Do you just want to attach it as a blob for retrieval?

Comment: I want get the file content including file attachment content.